# Xamarin Data Binding Not Updating

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding

My goal with this practice application is to open a "Edit Contact Page" and then return the data to be shown on the main page.

Currently, I'm able to pass the binding context to the ContactEdit page but, the change doesn't reflect in the main page.
Even after inputting text in the ContactEdit page and navigating to the main page, I can return to the ContactEdit page and see the changed data. 
I just don't understand what I'm missing to update/show this information on the main page.

Here is how my code is drawn out

For my Model, I have the Contact.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace DulyNoted.Models
{
    public class Contact
    {
        public string Name //automatic properties
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Position
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string PhoneNumber
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Email
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have my ContactServices.cs to act upon the model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using DulyNoted.Models;

namespace DulyNoted.Services
{
    public class ContactServices
    {
        public ContactServices()
        {

        }

        public Contact GetContacts()
        {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.Name = "Jane Doe";
            contact.Position = "Staff Member";
            contact.PhoneNumber = "6175550181";
            contact.Email = "JaneDoe@gmail.com";
            return contact;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have an implementation for ViewModelBase.cs which implements INotifyPropertychanged.
This is inherited by ContactViewModel.cs, as shown below.

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Text; using DulyNoted.Models; 
using DulyNoted.Services;

namespace DulyNoted.ViewModels 
{
    public class ContactViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private Contact contactList;

        public ContactViewModel()
        {
            var service = new ContactServices();

            ContactList = service.GetContacts();
        }

        public Contact ContactList
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref contactList, value); }
            get { return contactList; }
        }
    } 
}
```

My MainPage.xaml.cs I created a property so my button would refer to the same ContactViewModel as the main page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using DulyNoted.Models;
using DulyNoted.ViewModels;
using DulyNoted.Views;

namespace DulyNoted
{
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ContactViewModel contactViewModel;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            contactViewModel = new ContactViewModel();
            this.BindingContext = contactViewModel;

        }

        async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            var contactEditPage = new ContactEdit();
            contactEditPage.BindingContext = contactViewModel;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(contactEditPage);
        }
    }
}
```

The initial binding works, as my labels show properties of the contact (MainPage.xaml)

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="DulyNoted.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding ContactList.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding ContactList.Position, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding ContactList.PhoneNumber, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding ContactList.Email, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Button x:Name="EditContact" Text="Click to Edit Contact" Clicked="OnButtonClicked"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

When I navigate to the ContactEdit.xaml; I see my initial binding fill in, which shows that my other view is getting information from the view model.

```
For reference my ContactEdit.xaml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="DulyNoted.Views.ContactEdit">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Entry x:Name="NameEntry" Placeholder="Name" Text="{Binding ContactList.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Entry x:Name="PositionEntry" Placeholder="Position" Text="{Binding ContactList.Position, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Entry x:Name="PhoneNumberEntry" Placeholder="PhoneNumberEntry" Text="{Binding ContactList.PhoneNumber, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Entry x:Name="EmailEntry" Placeholder="EmailEntry" Text="{Binding ContactList.Email, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <!--<Button x:Name="SaveContact" Text="Save Contact" Clicked="OnSaveButtonClicked"/>-->
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Then here is where the user would "change information regarding the contact". Once they are done, they navigate back to the previous page. Unfortunately my main page still shows the old information on the labels. I can even navigate again to the ContactEdit page and see my changed values. I don't understand why the binding on my main page doesn't update.

I'm assuming I made a really obvious mistake as I'm still very new to MVVM, etc. I probably have the wrong idea about "data binding" and just having a rough time pass information between views.

Thanks for any advice you can give or pointers!

Comment: Contact does not implement INPC, so changes made to it's properties will not update the UI

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't even realize that was missing.

Comment: @ArcadeAcedia Hi , have you solved that ? If so, you can update solution in answer . Then other people will know the solution .